# SQL Server: apply regex with replacement

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Here's my SQL query:

```
select codi_nivell 
from anc_documents
```

Example data is:

```
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
```

I need to apply this regex to my SQL query:

Firstly, I need to remote trailing `0`.

Then apply this regex in order to add an `/` every two digits:

```
regex: \d{2}(?=(?:\d{2})+$)
replace: $0/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions - so, instead of showing us the regular expression, you better show us your desired results. Also, while you're at it, show us [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and your current attempts.

Comment: If you do need true Regex support in SQL Server, you'll need to implement CLR functions.

Comment: Do all of your strings have the same format as show in your question?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions.  But you can do this using some string manipulations and recursive CTEs:

```
with ad as (
      select row_number() over (order by code) as seqnum, replace(rtrim(replace(code, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') as new_code
      from anc_documents
     ),
     cte as (
      select seqnum, new_code, 0 as offset, 0 as lev
      from ad
      union all
      select seqnum, stuff(new_code, offset + 3, 0, '-'), offset + 3, lev + 1
      from cte
      where offset + 3 < len(new_code) 
     )
select *
from (select max(lev) over (partition by seqnum) as max_lev, cte.*
      from cte
     ) cte
where max_lev = lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e1a7182a178f7b61e375eba49c8faad) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by use of XML PATH:

```
DECLARE @codi_nivell NVARCHAR(100) = (SELECT REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE('06080100000000') AS BIGINT)))

;WITH cte AS(
 SELECT @codi_nivell AS codi_nivell, LEFT(@codi_nivell, 2) AS codi_nivell_left, RIGHT(@codi_nivell, LEN(@codi_nivell)-2) AS codi_nivell_right
 UNION ALL
 SELECT @codi_nivell, LEFT(codi_nivell_right, 2), RIGHT(codi_nivell_right, LEN(codi_nivell_right)-2)
   FROM cte
   WHERE LEN(codi_nivell_right) >= 2
)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '/' + c2.codi_nivell_left
  FROM cte c2
  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') y
  FROM cte c1
  GROUP BY c1.codi_nivell
```