# SQL Server : remove trailing "0" chracter from varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Here's my SQL query:

```
select codi_nivell 
from anc_documents
```

Example data is:

```
06080100000000
06080102000000
06080101010000
06080103040100
06080102000000
06080103040000
06080100000000
06080101020000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
06080100000000
```

I need to remove the trailing `0` from `varchar`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64749676/2029983), just without the regex requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option:

```
select codi_nivell,
    replace(rtrim(replace(codi_nivell, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') new_codi_nivell
from anc_documents
```

The trick is to replace all `0`s with `' '`, then use `rtrim()` to remove the trailing spaces, and finally replace remaining spaces with `0`s.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a07c8f197cd014533af592a4988ae8ad)**:

```
codi_nivell    | new_codi_nivell
:------------- | :--------------
06080100000000 | 060801         
06080102000000 | 06080102       
06080101010000 | 0608010101     
06080103040100 | 060801030401   
06080102000000 | 06080102       
06080103040000 | 0608010304     
06080100000000 | 060801         
06080101020000 | 0608010102     
06080100000000 | 060801         
06080100000000 | 060801         
06080100000000 | 060801         
06080100000000 | 060801
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative idea, using the `TRIM` function (introduced in SQL Server 2017):

```sql
SELECT STUFF(TRIM('0' FROM '#' + codi_nivell),1,1,'')
FROM anc_documents;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe223addf7502cd5b7582452a972cc24)

Comment: It's worth noting that `TRIM(... FROM)` is a fairly recent innovation (SQL Server 2017).

Comment: Correct, @JeroenMostert . When an OP doesn't tag a version, I *assume* that they have access to the latest version. ;)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, but since many people can be expected to still be on older versions, it's also not a bad idea to specify it only works on 2017+/Azure. The answer ultimately isn't just for the OP, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Here a slightly diffferent approach:

```
SELECT REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(codi_nivell) AS BIGINT))
  FROM anc_documents;
```

Comment: This answer assumes the coding would always be numeric. That is a dangerous assumption in varchar columns