# Remove trailing slash after substitution

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove trailing `[/]00/` from a given string.

Examples:

```
string: '01/00/00/00/00/00/00/' -> 01
string: '01/02/03/00/00/00/00/' -> 01/02/03
string: '10/25/03/56/00/00/00/' -> 10/25/03/56
```

I've been strugling with that but I don't quite figure out how to remove `[/]` from `[/]00`.

I mean, replaced expression must to avoud ending with an `/`.

I've tried with this expression:

```
\d{2}\/(?=(?:\d{2}\/)+$)
```

Matches are:

It's confused to me...

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your current regex.

Comment: I've not been able to write any minimal working expression

Comment: You can use: `str = str.replaceFirst("(?:/00)+/?$", "");`

Comment: `/(?:00/)+$` [will do](https://regex101.com/r/Sj1dfi/1). `\d{2}\/(?=(?:\d{2}\/)+$)` extracts any 2 digit sequence that is followed with 1+ occurrences of 2 digits + `/` till the end of string.

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64750545/2029983) this feels like another duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64749676/2029983) but with the SQL requirement instead of the Regex requirement removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex, `/00|(?<=(00))/` which means `/00` OR `/` preceded by `00`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "01/00/00/00/00/00/00/", "01/02/03/00/00/00/00/", "10/25/03/56/00/00/00/" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + s.replaceAll("/00|(?<=(00))/", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
01/00/00/00/00/00/00/ => 01
01/02/03/00/00/00/00/ => 01/02/03
10/25/03/56/00/00/00/ => 10/25/03/56
```

**Note:** `?<=` is used to specify [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

Alternativ:

```
Pattern.compile("/00|/$", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input).replaceAll("");
```

Note: The boundary matcher '$' will taken into account when the flag Pattern.MULTILINE is used.

Regex shown in testbench and context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "01/00/00/00/00/00/00/\n"
            + "01/02/03/00/00/00/00/\n"
            + "10/25/03/56/00/00/00/";

    String result = Pattern.compile("/00|/$", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(input).replaceAll("");

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
01
01/02/03
10/25/03/56
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for lookahead or lookbehind.  Just look for a slash followed by any number of `00/` sequences:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("/(00/)*$", "");
```

For better performance, you can make the group a non-capturing group:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("/(?:00/)*$", "");
```

Comment: Right, no lookarounds are necessary. Basically, it is the same as [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64767747/java-regex-remove-trailing-slash-after-substitution?noredirect=1#comment114515372_64767747), just the `*` quantifier here is used to match zero or more occurrences of `00/` after `/` and up to the end of string.